# How to remove ConditionalExpression from output

Tags: output, conditional

I need define the function with parameter so I could directly generate a power series expansion. The problem is that in some cases ConditionalExpression appears in output.  Here is my code:

```
S[x_, l_] := 
  (C[1] + 
     Integrate[
       E^(2 Sum[t^i/i, {i, 1, l - 1}])*(1 - t)^2*
         Sum[(l - i*2)*t^i, {i, 1, l - 1}]/((t - 1)*t^l), 
       {t, 1, x}])*
   x^(l - 1)*E^(-2 Sum[x^i/i, {i, 1, l - 1}])/(1 - x)^2; 

Table[S[x, i], {i, 2, 3}] // TableForm
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 2] , {x, 0, 3}], x]
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 3] , {x, 0, 3}], x]
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 3][[1]] , {x, 0, 3}], x]
```

Comment: Why not make up a rule (if you are sure of the `True`ness of your conditional) `rule = ConditionalExpression[a_, b__] -> a` and apply it to the output? i.e. `CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 3], {x, 0, 3}], x] /. rule`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `GenerateConditions->False` to eliminate conditions (assuming they do not affect your planned use):

```
S[x_, l_] := (C[1] + 
     Integrate[
      E^(2 Sum[t^i/i, {i, 1, l - 1}]) (1 - t)^2*
       Sum[(l - i*2) t^i, {i, 1, l - 1}]/((t - 1) t^l), {t, 1, x}, 
      GenerateConditions -> False]) x^(l - 1)*
   E^(-2 Sum[x^i/i, {i, 1, l - 1}])/(1 - x)^2;
Table[S[x, i], {i, 2, 3}] // TableForm
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 2], {x, 0, 3}], x]
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 3], {x, 0, 3}], x]
CoefficientList[Series[S[x, 3][[1]], {x, 0, 3}], x]
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `GenerateConditions -> False` as there are many cases where adding this option results in Mma either not being able to solve the integral, or returning a different answer than it otherwise would do. In my experience, a better approach is to let it do its thing, and then remove the `ConditionalExpression`

Answer (score 24):

A more general way, which can be used for other functions like `Solve`, is to use `Normal`.

```
Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]

(* ConditionalExpression[1/(-1 + s), Re[s] > 1] *)

Normal[%, ConditionalExpression]

(* 1/(-1 + s) *)
```

### Edit

It looks like as of version 10, one can just use the one argument `Normal`:

```
Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]

(* ConditionalExpression[1/(-1 + s), Re[s] > 1] *)

Normal[%]

(* 1/(-1 + s) *)
```

Comment: Just as a note for prefix form: `Normal@f'[x]` does not seem to work. `Normal@(f'[x])` rectifies the issue.

Comment: Correct. `@` appears above `'` in this list: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html.

Answer (score 6):

It might be late to answer this, but I think it's important to add my approach.

I came to the same problem of having ConditionalExpressions in my outputs.

After googling I came about [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/444685?_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.wolfram.com%2Fdashboard%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_groupId%3D0%26_3_keywords%3DConditionalExpression%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch%26_3_redirect%3D%252Fweb%252Fcommunity%252F) solution, by using the `Assuming[]` function.

An example:

```
Assuming[Re[s] > 1, Integrate[1/x^s,{x,1,Infinity}]
```

Which gives:

```
1/(-1+s)
```

Comment: What are cases where `Normal` didn't work?

Comment: Normal[] worked after all too.

Comment: Normal does a whole bunch of other stuff other than removing the assumption. You will have much more control using Assuming and won't inadvertently cause any unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming[Re[s] > 1, 
  Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]]
is the fastest way to do an integral. If you don't know the conditions for which the integral works, you can also use
Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]

Normal[Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]]
is significatively longer because you must compute the conditions and then throw them away. It can be very long in some cases.

For example,

```
In[215]:= Normal[Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[215]= {0.319937,1/(s-1)}

In[212]:= 
Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[212]= {0.140617,1/(s-1)}

In[214]:= 
Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> s > 1] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[214]= {0.148892,1/(s-1)}

In[219]:= 
Assuming[Re[s] > 1, 
  Integrate[1/x^s, {x, 1, Infinity}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[219]= {0.103522,1/(s-1)}
```