# 1/x integration giving 0 instead of infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I stumbled across the fact this integral:

```
Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

returns

```
0
```

Anybody understand why this is zero and not divergent? Is "GenerateConditions" doing something weird?

Comment: We do not put the [tag:bugs] tag into questions until your observed behavior has been confirmed by others as a bug.

Comment: Anyway: what does `Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, x}, GenerateConditions -> False]` return?

Comment: It returns `Log[x]`. But `Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]` returns `0` again.

Comment: Well, that at least explains the $0$ result…

Comment: One my favorite trick questions for calculus students: `Integrate[1/y^2, {y, 0, 2}, GenerateConditions -> False]` yields `-1/2`, both by *M* and by many students' hand calculations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 can you please explain more? Why does `GenerateConditions -> False]` make mathematica ignore the singularity at y=0? Is this a bug, or is there a mathematical reason why this makes sense?

Comment: I don't understand completely, but `GenerateConditions` turns off some checking. In particular, it turns off the step that checks convergence.  What I don't understand is why it throws out the limit at `0` -- it calculates it, gets `-Infinity` and then seems to remove the singular part.  Reminds me of something my roommate in grad school, who was in physics, said about one of his classes: whether the integral came out `0` or `Infinity`, in both cases the result was negligible. I don't really have a complete answer, but may it will be easier to discuss it in an answer...

Comment: If your goal with `GenerateConditions -> False` is to get rid of `ConditionalExpression`, [consider using `Normal` instead](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38620/12).

Answer (score 20):

*Summary:* Setting `GenerateConditions -> False` turns off safety checks. In my opinion, when the user does that and the result is erroneous, I would not call that a bug.  Now WRI could decide to improve *Mathematica* in this case, but it might not be such a simple matter.  On the other hand, it is entirely up to the user to decide whether or not he or she is satisfied with such limitations.  The analysis below shows that *Mathematica* does "plug in" `y == 0` and gets `-Infinity`: I think it would be an easy matter to be able to emit a message about possible divergence and suggest using the option `GenerateConditions -> True`.  See also [When to use GenerateConditions -> True](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46453/when-to-use-generateconditions-true) and [What exactly does GenerateConditions do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do).

From [How much time should one give Mathematica for an integral evaluation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85452/how-much-time-should-one-give-mathematica-for-an-integral-evaluation/85489#85489), one can monitor the progress of `Integrate` by setting

```
Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch = 10
```

The output is mainly inscrutable and for internal use at WRI, but if you've ever been able to read a mathematical paper in a language you don't understand, you can pick out important points now and then.

In a single integral, `GenerateConditions -> Automatic` is equivalent to `GenerateConditions -> True`. One of the differences between

```
GenerateConditions -> False
GenerateConditions -> True
```

is that the `False` setting turns off convergence testing.
If we set `debugSwitch = 10`, we get `Print` statements in the output at various steps as `Integrate` figures out the integral.  After 11 initialization steps, we see that there is a branch (after the last "start main' statement).  The computation with `GenerateConditions -> True` enters the "exception locus" routine, which ultimately determines the integral diverges.  The OP's integral enters "SimpPredicates", which sounds like a simplified check of the integrand; it is followed by a "dispatcher" which calls "Simpdispatcher", which again sounds like a simplified integrator.

```
Block[{Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch = 10},
 Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch = 10},
 Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> False]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As one scrolls through the output of the `GenerateConditions -> False` computation, one sees that `Log[y]` is found to be the antiderivative. Its limit is taken as `y -> 1` from below; and then the limit is taken as `y -> 0` from above:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After this point, I do not have a clear idea of what happens.  Apparently dissatisfied with `-Infinity`, `Integrate` essentially computes `Series[Log[y], {y, 0, 2}]`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is not clear from the output what is done with this result. A very few steps after, the `Log[y]` disappears and the result `0` appears; after several simplification steps, `0` is the answer.

The same thing happens when `1/y^2` is integrated.  Different things happen when the integrand is `1/(1 + y^2)`, which should be expected. `Integrate` is quite complicated.

---

If you know that for multivariable integrals, `GenerateConditions -> Automatic` means that the inner integral(s) will be computed with the setting `GenerateConditions -> False` and the outer integral is integrated with the setting `GenerateConditions -> True`, you should be able to predict the difference in these two integrals:

```
Integrate[1/y, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
Integrate[1/y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second result might be considered a bug, I suppose.  (I'm not sure who would have predicted the unnecessary second message, although you might infer why.)

If one adds the option `GenerateConditions -> True` to the last integral, one gets the expected divergence message (and only once):

```
Integrate[1/y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update:* See also [Why does Mathematica say $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1.0}{xyz}\,dz\,dy\,dx=0$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83957/why-does-mathematica-say-int-01-int-01-int-01-frac1-0xyz-dz-dy-dx-0).

Comment: "when the user does that and the result is erroneous, I would not call that a bug" - pretty much why I removed the initial [tag:bugs] tag; I think of it like the safety mechanism on a rifle. Disable it if and only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @J. M. Then should Mathematica not generate a warning that its answer might be wrong?

Comment: @Calchas, it's on by default, which is where the usual warnings come from. Since you've explicitly told *Mathematica* **not** to warn you… ;)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wouldn't say it was explicit to me! I've been using Mathematica for a year or two now and I am still surprised by what I would call a "bug" but on here is described as "intended feature" ;) To me it seems at odds with the Wolfram philosophy.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I don't know ... this behaviour is making me quite uncomfortable. There's also the two-variable example where the problem comes up without the user passing options.  And there's the fact that with `GenerateConditions -> True`, the result isn't something like `ConditionalExpression[0, False]` which would explain where the 0 is coming from.  It smells like a bug to me.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I'd concur that the double integral example looks to be a bug, but ever since `GenerateConditions` became built-in, I was always of the philosophy that it's not something you shut off unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing. So, if the calculus functions suddenly take wrong limits in that case, I'd say it's a classical case of GIGO.

Comment: Reviewing the docs for `GenerateConditions` I don't see the part about turning off safety checks, or how only experts should use it and should be prepared to be happy with patently wrong results.

Comment: @george2079 That's a good point. Reference (non-doc.) added. The documentation lags behind development in several areas it seems.  I've solved a lot of problems from information on this site that I don't think I could have from just the documentation. (OTOH, anyone can execute `Trace[cmd, TraceInternal -> True]` on a long winter evening. :) )

Comment: @george2079 And having read through the references I found, I notice that one is almost an exact duplicate of this one.

Comment: What a friggin' awesome answer. +1

Comment: `GenerateConditions` is a seriously overloaded option. Meanings include "check hard for convergence", "check for parameter provisos needed to make the result correct", "check for singular points along the integration path", "explicitly allow (or even assume) cancellation of singular parts of the integral". I'd say it is this last one at work in the example shown here.